# SQL: Creating temporary variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL so please consider this **noob** question. Also, its so embarrassing to admit that I cannot search for the right keyword in Google and I'm running out of time so I decided to ask it here.

Code:

```
select
 *,
 price * quantity as [Total price],
 case
   when [Total price]>100 and [Total price]<= 200 then '2%'
   when [Total price]>200 and [Total price]<= 300 then '3%'
   when [Total price]>300 and [Total price]<= 400 then '4%'
   else '0%'
 end as tax
from
grocery
```

As you can see, what I am trying to do is try to create a temporary variable on execution of SQL statement but, this one gives me error

`Error 1: could not prepare statement [1 no such column: Total price]`

How could I do this ?

Comment: Are you **sure** you are on SQL Server? That isn't a SQL Server error message. Googling "no such column" indicates that you are on sqlite.

Comment: @MartinSmith nope, Sorry for not stating it. I just try it @ [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick way would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression).  This allows you to pre-calculate some values and then refer the values in the body of the query.

If a statement with a CTE isn't the first thing in a batch, you need to end the preceding stuff with a `;`:

```
 ;
 With Totals as
 (
    select  *,
            price * quantity as [Total price],
    from    grocery
 )
 select  *
    ,  case
         when [Total price]>100 and [Total price]<= 200 then '2%'
         when [Total price]>200 and [Total price]<= 300 then '3%'
         when [Total price]>300 and [Total price]<= 400 then '4%'
        else '0%'
     end as tax
 from
   Totals
```

The root of your problem, by the way, is that you can't define an expression and then use the expression *by name* in a query.  You can re-use the expression, but not by name:

```
select  x + 1 as Expr1
   ,    (x + 1) * 2  as Expr2
from   Table1
```

That will work, but the following *won't* work:

```
select x + 1 as Expr1
   ,   Expr1 * 2 as Expr2   -- This won't work
from   Table1
```

Comment: I'm newbie in SQL so I cannot understand it fully but you got 1 vote for this, please tell me how does this one consider to be good/flexible/efficient against Yosi's first example answer? thanks :)

Comment: It's almost the same:  Yosi's first example uses a subquery.  A CTE is like taking a subquery and expressing it differently.  The advantage (in readability) is that you can use a CTE multiple times in a query, as if it were a table:  `with CTE1 as (select x + 1 as y from Table1) select * from CTE1 c1 join CTE1 c2 on c1.y = c2.y`  (That would be a pointless query, but you can see that I was able to reference CTE1 several times).  With a subquery, every time you need it, you'd have to restate the whole thing.

Comment: With a simple CTE and simple subquery, as in your case, they come out exactly the same as far as performance goes.  I happen to think CTEs are more readable, but YMMV.

Comment: CTEs are also much easier to build on:  you can do stepwise refinement of what you want, like this:  `with c1 as (select id, x+1 as y from Table1), c2 as (select id, sum(y) as z from c1 group by id), c3 as (select c2.id, y, y/z as yz from c2 join c1 on c2.id = c1.id) select * from c3`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,
 case
   when [Total price]>100 and [Total price]<= 200 then '2%'
   when [Total price]>200 and [Total price]<= 300 then '3%'
   when [Total price]>300 and [Total price]<= 400 then '4%'
   else '0%'
 end as tax
FROM (SELECT *, price * quantity as [Total price]
      FROM grocery) A
```

OR

```
select
 *,
 price * quantity as [Total price],
 case
   when price * quantity >100 and price * quantity<= 200 then '2%'
   when price * quantity>200 and price * quantity<= 300 then '3%'
   when price * quantity>300 and price * quantity<= 400 then '4%'
   else '0%'
 end as tax
from
grocery
```

Comment: The first example is what I am looking for but I'm still confused about the nesting happened here. Could you explain a little bit about that for me? thanks!

Comment: [Total price] doesn't exists in the context you were using it.. you can't give an alias and address it in the same SELECT clause..