# Is there a clean way to create a temporary variable within BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there any SQL update to this old question [SQL: Creating temporary variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811265/sql-creating-temporary-variables) ?

I have more-or-less the same problem, each row of a  BigQuery table is `Time, Data` where each row of `Data` is a JSON dictionary. One of the parameters therein is a string called `Table_ID` and the following works:

```
SELECT Time, JSON_VALUE(Data,"$.Table_ID") As Table_ID,
  JSON_QUERY(Data,"$.Q") From mytable where
  JSON_VALUE(Data,"$.Table_ID") LIKE "AB%" or 
    JSON_VALUE(Data,"$.Table_ID") LIKE "CD%"
```

But I don't like seeing all those repeated calls to JSON (and my real query is much longer), What I'd prefer is:

```
SELECT Time, JSON_VALUE(Data,"$.Table_ID") As Table_ID, JSON_QUERY(Data,"$.Q") 
From mytable where Table_ID LIKE "AB%" or Table_ID LIKE "CD%"
```

At least, I image that such an expression might be more performant, but this is invalid SQL. I've seen recommendation using CTE but the following is a disaster:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT JSON_VALUE(Data,"$.Table_ID") As Table_ID FROM mytable)
SELECT TIME, Table_ID, JSON_QUERY(Data,"$.Q") 
 FROM CTE, mytable WHERE Table_ID LIKE "AB%" or Table_ID LIKE "CD%"
```

BQ complains destination table too big. It's probably doing an outer join or something. What does work is to put the entirety of mytable, as well as the calculation of Table_ID, into the first CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT Time, Data, JSON_VALUE(Data,"$.Table_ID") As Table_ID FROM mytable)
SELECT TIME, Table_ID, JSON_QUERY(Data,"$.Q") 
 FROM CTE WHERE Table_ID LIKE "AB%" or Table_ID LIKE "CD%"
```

This avoids any kind of join and seems to be of comparable performance to my original query, but it is not noticeably faster.

Is there anything else I could try?

Thanks...

Comment: Your last query looks better to avoid having the repeating expressions ... however, I don't expect it to be more performant than the original query (just reads better).  For better performance, you might want to change the game.  Instead of story your "data" as a String representing a JSON object, consider storing it as the native column type called JSON see ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/json-data

Comment: It's an interesting idea to load the json object as, er, a json object instead of a string. This had not occurred to me. I will experiment. But talking about changing the game, I think I have settled on a different approach. I'm now creating a materialized view defined by JSON_VALUE(Data, "$.Table_ID"), JSON_VALUE(Data, "$.X1"), JSON_VALUE(Data, "$.X2"), etc, where I populate the view with the most likely tags that a user will want. Then from that view, Table_ID is already defined and waiting for the subsequent filter. Order of magnitude faster!

Comment: I just saw this blog post. Using Json object seems definitely something that I should have in my toolkit. Thanks for bringing to my attention. https://medium.com/@aroraashish1909/json-datatype-vs-string-datatype-for-storing-json-objects-bigquery-2719616c6da4